# Why can I only add nested teams to repositories on GitHub through command line

Tags: git, github, command-line, ldap, github-cli

I am trying to add several teams to my repository but it gives me a Not Found (HTTP 404 error). The teams are specifically an LDAP group

Here is the basic command Line for adding teams to a repo with special permission: `gh api --method PUT /orgs/eze/teams/TEAMS_NAME/repos/eze/REPO -f permission=PERMISSION`
Source: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/teams/teams?apiVersion=2022-11-28#add-or-update-team-repository-permissions

The source above

Interesting enough if I use a Nested teams for TEAMS_NAME then the command line works. However I don't want to do this because the child teams can only have one parent team Source:https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/organizing-members-into-teams/about-teams

Comment: How do you mean, you want your child teams to have more than one parent? As you point out, a team can only have one parent team.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I mean that I want to add team repository permissions. The only reason I had mentioned parents and child teams is because the command line as I mentioned in the question only worked when I had a nested team. Ideally I would like to use the command line to add team repositories without using nested teams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use nested teams on the command line as I mentioned in the question but then remove the parent teams. Such a simple answer but doesn't take much time at all to do